# No rule to process file for architecture armv6

Tags: iphone, xcode, project, armv6

I recently migrated to XCode 4.5 with iOS SDK 6.0. Now when i try to archive my app, i get a long list of compiler warnings all reading the same.

> warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/Classes/Utils.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6
>
> warning: architecture armv6 is not supported (current ARCHS = "armv7 armv6").

I cannot understand the last line, it says armv6 is not not supported,but armv6 is present as you can see.

1) How do i fix this?

[image: Screenshot of project file]

2) What could be the implication of this? as this is just a warning? Will my app update not run of iphone 3gs?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Xcode 4.5 has dropped support for armv6 as the warning says. The setting is showing because you had it in a previous version of your project. Just change your setting to compile for armv7 and armv7s (iPhone5).

Apple has decided to drop support for old devices and thus armv6 is deprecated. I decided to drop support for armv6 devices due to this. All armv7 devices can be upgraded to iOS 5, so I also set that as the minimum version supported.

Comment: just read a little more and all armv7 devices can install iOS 4.3+, hence you can set the minimum version as iOS 4.3 :)

Comment: @Neelesh my point was why support iOS 4.3 when all the users can upgrade to iOS 5. If there were any users, then they would never use my app anyway or figure out how to download it :)  
The value of going to iOS 5 is to get storyboards, ARC and so many others.